# CAML Query is ignoring date altogether

Tags: powershell, caml

I'm using posh 4.0 on SharePoint 2013 SP1 Enterprise on-premises running on Windows 2012 R2.
I have asked a question or 2 about CAML in the last week and have gotten my queries returning results as expected in most cases. TO create this one, that is returning zero results when it should return 1976, I created the view first on the SharePoint list and then used posh to return the view's query property. I am using the same query value that the view on the list is using. THe query asks for all items where the Created date is greater than or equal to the supplied date:

```
$query.Query = "<Where><Leq>
                  <FieldRef Name=""Created"" /><Value Type=""DateTime"">'$startdate'</Value>
                </Leq></Where>"
```

I am creating the $query object like this:

```
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
```

The output is:

```
<Where>
 <Leq>
  <FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime">'2018-01-01T00:00:00Z'</Value>
 </Leq>
</Where>
```

Then I make the request like so:

```
 $SPList = $web.Lists.TryGetList($list)
 $ListItems = $SPList.GetItems($query)
 $ListItems.Count
```

The last line returns 0 instead of 1976 as the sharepoint view does.

Answer (score 1):

After posting the question it becamse clear that there were single quotes around the date. I removed these and gott he expected results.